# Is there way to attach revisions to ticket in JIRA without writing ticket ID in commit-message

Tags: version-control, jira, dvcs, bitbucket

Im using Jira with Bitbucket, and I wonder - can I somehow store info about that one or more revisions are related to some ticket, without writing ugly prefixes like `ABC-123` in commit-messages?

Answer (score 0):

The only other solution is to login to JIRA UI and create an issue link to the commit  page in Bitbucket.

Obviously, this is somewhat more work than just adding `ABC-123` in the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: not really

The problem is that most version control systems don't allow you to store extra structured data related to a commit. The least common denominator is the commit message, so it tends to get used for all kinds of logically separate data, e.g. JIRA issue keys, change the status directions etc. The git notes feature might be used for this.